# Separate strings to variables

Tags: perl, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I want to separate everything after the colon: two separate values before and after.

```
Server Id: 9
Completed: 0
In Error: 0
Added To Queue: 0
Waiting: 0
In Progress: 0
Total Processed: 0
Processing Rate: 0
FinalStatus:0, GOOD
```

Expected View:

```
Server Id|9
Completed|0
...
```

I'm able to get just the last column of one row with:

```
grep -oP '(?<=:)\w+'
```

and am wondering how to separate the values.

Comment: After you separate them, *what do you want to do with them*?  Do you indeed want to print them as `a|b` ?  In that case, it's simpler to mutate the separator: `perl -pe 's/: */|/'`

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the separator to a pipe `|` character?

Comment: @JulianFondren: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple awk command will give you your output:

```
awk -F ":" '{sub(/^ +/, "", $2); print $1"|"$2}' file
```

But have to say that your question is vague and its not clear if this is really what you need.

Comment: if I want to split on different view how to do it for example:
`{"eventid":"Server Id,"status":"9"},`
I made 
`awk -F ":" '{sub(/^ +/, "", $2); print "{\"eventid\":\""$1",\"status\":\""$2""}'` but not able to add ("},) chars to the end.

Comment: What output do you expect for `{"eventid":"Server Id,"status":"9"}` ?

Comment: exactly that output want to make but not able to add last chars `("},)`

Comment: Ok so if `{"eventid":"Server Id,"status":"9"}` is your expected output , what is your input, since your question's input looks different?

Comment: ` awk -F ":" '{sub(/^ +/, "", $2); print "{\"eventid\":\""$1",\"status\":\""$2""}'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32754/discussion-between-anubhava-and-kalin-borisov)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the colon separator with a pipe character, then this one-line Perl program will do what you ask

```
perl -ne "print join '|', split /:\s*/" myfile
```

**output**

```
Server Id|9
Completed|0
In Error|0
Added To Queue|0
Waiting|0
In Progress|0
Total Processed|0
Processing Rate|0
FinalStatus|0, GOOD
```

Comment: Which replaces *all* `/:\s*/`, so "FinalStatus: 1, Error: too many separators" would get turned into "FinalStatus|1, Error|too many separators".  You can limit this to the first separator, if you like, with `split /:\s*/, $_, 2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more option using **Regex**

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/:\s?/|/; print $_' myfile
```

Output:

```
Server Id|9
Completed|0
In Error|0
Added To Queue|0
Waiting|0
In Progress|0
Total Processed|0
Processing Rate|0
FinalStatus|0, GOOD
```

Comment: There's no need to backslash the `|` on the right side of a `s///`, or to put `$_` in double quotes, or to explicitly `$_ =~`.  Please at least avoid the first: unnecessary backslashes are actively confusing, they make look special what isn't.

Comment: Try: `perl -ple's/\s*\:\s*/|/' file` See `perldoc perlrun` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Answer (score 1):

In GNU sed,

```
sed 's/ *: */|/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the task is really as simple as you suggest then here's a very simple answer:

```
tr ":" "|"  < file.txt
```

or in a `perl` version ;-)

```
perl -pe 'tr{:}{|}' file.txt
```